# Merge Python dictionaries and sort them using their key

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have created 2 python dictionaries. For simplicity,

```
dict1 = {'apple' : 'g1', 'banana' : 'g2', 'mango' : 'g3'}

dict2 = {'grapes' : 'a1', 'pear' : 'a2', 'apple' : 'a3', 'bananabc' : 'a4'}
```

I would like to merge them into one dictionary as shown:

```
merge_dict = {'apple' : ['g1', 'a3'], 'banana : ['g2','a4']', 'mango' : ['g3'], 'grapes' :  ['a1'], 'pear' : ['a2']}
```

So not only do I want to combine them into one dictionary, but also:

1. If it is the same value put it into one key
2. If it is a similar value e.g.(banana & bananabc) put it into one key
3. Else just update the dictionary

Is it possible to do that?

Here's what I have tried:

```
def match_product(name, list_names, min_score=0):

    max_score = -1
    max_name = ''

    for name2 in list_names:

        score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name, name2)
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = name2
            max_score = score

    return(max_name, max_score)
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: as it is said already it is perfectly possible, but stackoverflow will not write code for you. You have to show what you have tried and where you are having difficulties

Comment: Do you know how to do it? Or do you any reference?@mkrieger1

Comment: I have edited the post, could you share your thoughts on it? @NikosM.

Comment: Does the code you have written not work? If so, please explain in more detail what is not correct.

Comment: dict1 and dict2 - if declared the way you have.. are sets.. not dictionaries. To be dictionaries, they'd have to be declared the way the answers to this question show.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    merged = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for k in d:
            if k in merged: merged[k].append(d[k])
            else: merged[k] = [d[k]]
    return merged


dict1 = {'apple' : 'g1', 'banana' : 'g2', 'mango' : 'g3'}
dict2 = {'grapes' : 'a1', 'pear' : 'a2', 'apple' : 'a3', 'banana' : 'a4'}

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
print(merge_dicts(dict1, dict2))
```

[Online demo](https://repl.it/repls/FondHospitableDimension)

```
{'apple': 'g1', 'banana': 'g2', 'mango': 'g3'}
{'grapes': 'a1', 'pear': 'a2', 'apple': 'a3', 'banana': 'a4'}
{'apple': ['g1', 'a3'], 'banana': ['g2', 'a4'], 'mango': ['g3'], 'grapes': ['a1'], 'pear': ['a2']}
```

**Note** that default python dictionaries (`dict`) in general DO NOT pereserve key order. If you need key order try using the [`OrderedDict`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/) instead.

**Note2** If fuzzy key equality is needed try adjusting `merge_dicts` function to handle that. Else I do not have much information to provide that in answer here

Comment: Indeed this is a solution, but i forgot to mention that i need to implement a blocking method such that we can't use a double for loop because the algorithm needs to be linear

Comment: For loop is only used for merging multiple dicts it is still linear. But you can simplisfy it to merge only two dicts

Comment: the code works perfectly! However, i was wondering is it possible to add an elif statement that measures the difference between the key from dict1 and dict2. For example, using fuzz.token_sort_ratio that compares a similar key with each key from the merged dict while still keeping the algorithm linear ? @NikosM.

Comment: @StevenSugi, I dont know how this is supposed to work so I cant provide it. However if it needs to check each key against each other key, then you will have quadratic complexity at least. But I think it may be better to do the fuzzy matching AFTER you have already merged the dicts on the merged dict, take its keys and compare against each other and if they match, combine their values. Since I dont know how this is implemnted in your use case I cannot say more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Solution:

```
dict1 = {'apple' : 'g1', 'banana' : 'g2', 'mango' : 'g3'}

dict2 = {'grapes' : 'a1', 'pear' : 'a2', 'apple' : 'a3', 'bananabc' : 'a4'}

merge_dict={}

for key in dict2.keys():
    merge_dict[key]=[dict2[key],]

for key in dict1.keys():
    if key in merge_dict.keys():
        merge_dict[key].append(dict1[key])
    else:
        merge_dict[key]=dict1[key]

print(merge_dict)
```

Comment: however, this solution only output {'grapes': ['a1'], 'pear': ['a2'], 'apple': ['a3', 'g1'], 'bananabc': ['a4']}. While i need the other value in dict 2 which is not found in dict 1

Comment: It's ok now.. try it.